# How to get proxy info from WebClient object?

Tags: c#, webclient

I set the Proxy property for a WebClient object:

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("proxy server url and credentials here");
webClient.Proxy = wp;
```

How do I get proxy information like Host, Port, Username, Password from an existing WebClient object as a string?

For example:

```
            var test =
                webClient.Proxy as WebProxy;
            var test2 = test.Address;
            var test3 = webClient.Proxy.Credentials as NetworkCredential;
            var test4 = test3.UserName;
            var test5 = test3.Password;
```

But this doesn't work because the objects I get from Proxy and Proxy.Credentials are null.
How do I simply get those information?

Comment: I think there will be not magic wand here: You must get properties you want to log and assemble a string say with string.Format(...)

Comment: The problem is that I didn't find a way to get the properties from a WebClient object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy Uri is context bind, with other words for different original request a proxy configuration can provide different proxy Uris. To get an actual proxy  Uri (Host, Port, Protocoll, etc) you must provide the original Uri

```
Uri proxyUri = yourWebClient.Proxy.GetProxy(new Uri(originalRequestUrl))
```

or

```
Uri proxyUri = yourWebClient.Proxy.GetProxy(originalRequestUri)
```

then you can use the proxyUri variable's properties like Host, Port etc.

**Note: If you get back the original Uri that means: There was no proxy in effect.**

In case if providing the original request Uri is a problem for you, *and* you are sure the proxy is identical for all Uris, then ypi cam simply provide a dummmy (but valid) uri (although this is an ugly solution) like :

```
Uri proxyUri = yourWebClient.Proxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://www.google.com"))
```

Obviously this will not cause traffic to www.google.com, just getting the proxy configuration.

About the credentials the same story:

```
 NetworkCredential credential  = yourWebClient.Proxy.Credentials.GetCredential(...)
```

Via the credential variable you get the Domain, UserName and Password* properties.

(*Just for the record: Logging password is not a recommended practice)

Comment: For GetCredential it wants two parameters (Uri and AuthType)

Comment: For your sample I get as proxy host "www.google.com" and as port "80" instead of the proxy host and port that I set for the webClient.

Comment: You are right, if there is no proxy you get back the original Uri. If there is a proxy then you will got back the proxy address instead of the original Uri. Also see my edit.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I set the proxy for the webClient (Proxy property of WebClient object). So I want this proxy information (see my updated question).

Comment: If the Proxy property were set _and_ the containing information points to a proxy then you will get the real proxy information. If you even set the Proxy property, but that proxy instance is not containing data to a proxy server, the http communication is still transparent, so you will get the original Uri.

Comment: With other words: You will get the _effective_ Uri, where the requests will be sent. If this is identical with the original Uri, that means there is not proxy server in the chain, regardless how many property was set. Try with a _real_ proxy, if you do not have one, the use fiddler. In case Fiddler is started (which is a local proxy) you will get: 127.0.0.1 and port 8888 (supposing the default settings)